# UWP MapControl huge nr of MapIcons

Tags: uwp, observablecollection, uwp-maps

The thing is that I cannot see all 20.000 MapIcons at once and I'd like to increase the number of MapIcons even more.

I have a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<House>` prop called `Houses` in my ViewModel `HousesViewModel`

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    HousesVM.Houses.CollectionChanged += Houses_CollectionChangedAsync;
    GetInitialPins();
}
```

My `GetInitialPins()` had a foreach to add/fill the HousesVm.Houses but that seemed inefficient so I rewrote it like this:

```
List<House> houses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<House>>(response);
HousesVM.Houses = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<House>(houses);
```

The downside is that this does not fire the `CollectionChanged` event in which I added the MapIcons.

```
private async void Houses_CollectionChangedAsync(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
    {
        foreach (House item in e.NewItems)
        {
            MapIcon myPOI = new MapIcon
            {
                Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = item.Latitude, Longitude = item.Longitude }),
                NormalizedAnchorPoint = normalizedAnchorPoint,
                Title = item.Name,
                CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible,
                ZIndex = 0
            };

            await mappie.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                mappie.MapElements.Add(myPOI);
            });    
        }
    });
}
```

I have also tried to move away from `MapIcon` and just add `Ellipse` to the children of the mapcontrol. That gave me an out of memory exception. Also tried to bind in XAML:

```
<map:MapControl x:Name="mappie" 
                        MapServiceToken="mysecrettoken"
                        Grid.Row="1">
        <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Houses}">
            <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock map:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" Text="{Binding Code}" map:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5" FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl>
```

Also gave an out of memory exception... Have also seen that the js version of bing maps has a cluster/grouping feature. which is not there in uwp. And also seen in the docs that with large quantity I should consider building a tile service and reference custom created tiles... That seems an overkill for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering is the recommended method of dealing with a very large number of points since as you noted you really can't see all of them at the same time anyway. 
There is a clustering example in the UWP maps sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl

Comment: I have found the right sample (scenario 7). It's just that clustering is not really build in. Its a nice implementation. Thank you for pointing out the sample code! https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/MapControl/cs/Scenario7.xaml.cs